# Plot data using D3.js and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask, d3.js, xmlhttprequest

I want to plot the iris dataset(iris.csv) using D3.js. So how to get data using AJAX and send responseText into D3 function for plotting. I am using a flask server.

**Flask Code:**

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/plot")
def plotIris():
    return render_template("plot.html")
```

**plot.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CSV Test</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
         
         .....// using get method in ajax how to get responseText and given responseText into D3 function for ploting?
         ...... //ajaxcode

         function plotIrisData(responseText) {
            var outerWidth = 300;
            var outerHeight = 250;
            var rMin = 5; // "r" stands for radius
            var rMax = 20;
            var xColumn = "sepal_length";
            var yColumn = "petal_length";
            var rColumn = "sepal_width";

            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", outerWidth)
                .attr("height", outerHeight);

            var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, outerWidth]);
            var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([outerHeight, 0]);
            var rScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([rMin, rMax]);

        function render(data){
            xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d){ return d[xColumn]; }));
            yScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d){ return d[yColumn]; }));
            rScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d){ return d[rColumn]; }));

            var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data);
            circles.enter().append("circle");
            circles
                .attr("cx", function (d){ return xScale(d[xColumn]); })
                .attr("cy", function (d){ return yScale(d[yColumn]); })
                .attr("r",  function (d){ return rScale(d[rColumn]); });
            circles.exit().remove();
        }
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here **plot.html** in script tag using get method in ajax how to get iris.csv file and plot using D3?

Answer (score 0):

Place your CSV file in your static folder in the app's root directory (create one if you don't have one yet), then write a view function that serves it using Flask's `send_from_directory` function, which you can then hit with an AJAX call client-side via d3's `d3.csv(...)` function (see an example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/JohnDelacour/5571901)).